# DialogFlow CX session ends soon after filling an intent parameter

Tags: parameters, conditional-statements, dialogflow-es

I have an entity **[Feeling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHGGQ.png)** in DialogFlow CX. It is categorized into one of the 3 values based upon user input as **Positive** (happy, awesome, great etc) **Negative** (bad, angry, ugly etc) or **Medium**( OK, fair, fine etc).

Now I have different message responses/routes for these 3 types of feelings. I saw that the agent detects correctly from these three entity types and fill parameter value with one of them.

So I have conditions like:
**$session.params.feeling = "positive",
$session.params.feeling = "negative", $session.params.feeling = "medium"** for each route, to respond accordingly.
The problem is that, the parameter gets value correctly but soon after session ends without any transitions.
[Filled Parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgeKD.png)
Also I have set this parameter to **Required** Looks like I am not using condition syntax properly.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

On the screenshot of your agent test in the Dialogflow CX simulator, the parameter name is "personal-feeling".

You need to use the same parameter name in your conditions. For example, the first condition would be `$session.params.personal-feeling = "positive"`.